# Using Perl extract data between two symbols line by line from a log file

Tags: perl

I have to extract data between two symbols (`:` and `;`) line by line from a log file. My data is:

```
INFO @3035155 mti_lane1_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 3035155; T=3035155
```

I'm using this code to extract data after colon (`:`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'log1';
my @fields;
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";
while(<FILE>)
{
chomp;
@fields = split(':', $_);

print "$fields[1]\n";
}
close FILE;
```

Current output:

```
total bytes = 0, at time = 3035155; T=3035155
```

Required output:

```
total bytes = 0, at time = 3035155
```

Actually I have to compare two different log files line by line and print all lines of log1 that are not in log2. I have used this approach but answer is not coming right. Now my updated code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use 5.012;

my $filename1 = 'log2';
my %a_links;

open(FILE, $filename1) or die "Could not read from $filename1, program halting.";
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my @fields1 = split(/[:;]/, $_);
    print "$fields1[1]\n";
    $a_links{$fields1[1]} = undef;

}
close FILE;

my $filename2 = 'log1';
my @fields;
open(FILE, $filename2) or die "Could not read from $filename2, program halting.";
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    @fields = split(/[:;]/, $_);
    next if exists $a_links{$fields[1]}; 
    print "$fields[1] \n";
}

close FILE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you can use regular expressions to split upon?

Try

```
@fields = split(/[:;]/, $_);
```